# Пропал счётчик FB

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

говорят в FB что-то поменялось

с недавних пор, даже в базовом конструкторе (share-кнопок Yandex) не отображается счётчик FB, и не резервируется место под его отображение

и на сайте, куда встроен код счётчика, тоже пропал счётчик

https://iocs.hse.ru/announcements/236638175.html

Yandex-поддержка игнорирует сообщения об этом, как будто это само собой разумеющееся поведение и счётчика нет и не было…

вот на сайте самой платформы:

https://tech.yandex.ru/share/

раздел счётчики

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Так решения и нет? Самый лучший счетчик шар - очень жаль его терять..

Answer (score 1):

В [доках](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/troubleshooting-docpage/#troubleshooting__facebook) есть упоминание проблем с FB

> Вы используете устаревший блок «Поделиться». Обновите его до актуальной версии.

Но, задавшись вопросом, почему же тогда в демке на сайте яндекса не отображается счетчик, я нажал на него, и заветная единичка появилась:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Статьей](https://iocs.hse.ru/announcements/236638175.html) из вашего примера я тоже поделился:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]